# Output comma instead of DOT on MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

I´ve got a SQL QUERY that outputs a file which is loaded into EXCEL, but the sum column contains dot as decimal separator , which excel cannot understand, I need to show the sum with a comma separator (eg. 2,75).

This is what I have:

```
SELECT
ROUND((SUM(TOT_NR_HORS_TRBL)/8),2) HOURS_MD,
```

The sum is supposed to convert hours worked into working days (/8)

This is how it is shown: 2.75

This is how it is supposed to be: 2,75

Comment: Share some sample input with expected output.

Comment: Look into MySQL's [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function..

Comment: No @Vebbie not like that the `REPLACE()` should **not** be nested in the `SUM()` function.. `REPLACE()` should be the nesting function for `SUM()` and `ROUND()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland : ohk. My bad.. I had referred that somewhere..  Thank you for correcting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope its working

```
SELECT Replace(ROUND((SUM(TOT_NR_HORS_TRBL)/8),2),'.',',') HOURS_MD
```

Comment: Perfect! That is what I was looking for!